# connect more than 10 devices through wifi direct?

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifi-direct, wifip2p

I dont have much devices to test and be sure about maximum number of connections through wifi direct.
I know that the number of connections depends on the device but I'm unable to find any document about any device about this.
I've Galaxy s4 and so far i've connected 4 android phones with it and it works..
can i connect more then 10 devices with s4 or any other device through WIFI Direct?

Comment: The amount of connections that can be supported also depends on Wi-Fi hardware itself.

Answer (score 2):

I read some time ago a paper (I don't remember which was). In this document some researchers said that the maximum was 15. But, I never reached this number. I connected 6 devices successfully on a Nexus 5 (I don't remember if I used android's api or wpa_supplicant on a root device).

I worked for months on this topic and in my opinion, the Android implementation is very unstable and unpredictable. I had problems also with 3 devices. I really can't imagine a group of 10 Android devices.